# SAML SSO to Google suite: "G Suite - This account cannot be accessed because we could not parse the login request."

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

I'm passing saml response & RelayState parameters for Google SSO from my python application.
My SAML Response is:

samlp:response ..

```
@xmlns:samlp:urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol
@xmlns:saml:urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion
@ID:_cfc7299955d2075f71b4f1fbc821f3ec2c17c1fd6b
@Version:2.0
@IssueInstant:2017-05-23T10:51:29Z
@Destination:https://www.google.com/a/q3web.xyz/acs
@InResponseTo:adkcgeadlnldphjjmkibfopehpmpomapchiamhip
saml:issuerhttp://192.168.11.122:8000/saml2/idp/metadata.php
-
ds:signature ..
    @xmlns:ds:http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#
    ds:signedinfo ..
        ds:canonicalizationmethod
            @Algorithm:http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#
        -
        ds:signaturemethod
            @Algorithm:http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1
        -
        ds:reference ..
            @URI:#_cfc7299955d2075f71b4f1fbc821f3ec2c17c1fd6b
            ds:transforms ..
                ds:transform
                    @Algorithm:http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature
                -
                ds:transform
                    @Algorithm:http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#
                -
            -
            ds:digestmethod
                @Algorithm:http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1
            -
            ds:digestvaluet25Qo2lZ7qBbW2uF/uVMBlugxsQ=
            -
        -
    -
    ds:signaturevalueMIICdQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCAl8wggJbAgEAAoGBALNd029is/ZC83IR iCnQGIUYj+dHVODUzL3anFbQHBn0aDvnsUvgshaq1yrM5GFiHFDty+rJ+NVdoA1K vzX7IRkdDPvyXbcRhlrs+A+hPNd3QgDRQfEHdywrl6jde9D9o1HTi0NOAS1sMwWb onG2qEgygt2bCDTf7ibC8ZU3Hka3AgMBAAECgYBEucOk3yXjSt3qrAsHMmPiw3mH /Y3pI8BbUmMq5EyQKVSy92C4mRzDkKwnCyDKq4P8AlFq4f6FCn2j+irvrQyN5RJt 0e+oqNMHcwEimZmMX3ynjiWiRNHdqN0jQF5Iywr1qGKetltv5XqLjgGvN0rBETcF Lh6IngDJDtTHdMLDqQJBAOhddLROdXtKjeI70hUFGJxTP+jEnz4+ZiRekJ7QDznC gTiMcJNPzyKEHe8Sb8XgGkXPfCkr7gzE6jcppa/4H60CQQDFnFfIPo2/LcfH9sr2 K42K/Dhpshfn6BPL4ax1/gbZ/jrPiUbgzJsmuJG6EXALP28J6GEJGi6JF5vzx3a5 mbxzAkBR2kn4EgNUcQjV/ticSvVGbBUBO/IUjQqSGTW8m/IhGKFIeEBXxC9lK0EY LFhvTegzW0mTf0QV/2+6CtOwzyjpAkBM1nT/pOsi+l8jbuAOhnLcJyScXKaVAxWn glG385WgcA1YI23O/WAa10u6yQsDJKA9fwE0M90Ca461ZMrScmfnAkAbMYBnQ2cj PGEgDO3VjrThSUg2HMxY46+C9j99cbZp0Sy/Yw9iWwY/Upvi7/femXG2jkD0GuAI fwKkQ0/8ZBie
    -
    ds:keyinfo ..
        ds:x509data ..
            ds:x509certificateMIICbjCCAdcCAgPoMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAMH8xCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVLMQ8wDQYD VQQIDAZMb25kb24xDzANBgNVBAcMBkxvbmRvbjEaMBgGA1UECgwRRHVtbXkgQ29t cGFueSBMdGQxGjAYBgNVBAsMEUR1bW15IENvbXBhbnkgTHRkMRYwFAYDVQQDDA1k aXZ5YS1kZXNrdG9wMB4XDTE3MDUyMzA5NDgxN1oXDTI3MDUyMTA5NDgxN1owfzEL MAkGA1UEBhMCVUsxDzANBgNVBAgMBkxvbmRvbjEPMA0GA1UEBwwGTG9uZG9uMRow GAYDVQQKDBFEdW1teSBDb21wYW55IEx0ZDEaMBgGA1UECwwRRHVtbXkgQ29tcGFu eSBMdGQxFjAUBgNVBAMMDWRpdnlhLWRlc2t0b3AwgZ8wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQAD gY0AMIGJAoGBAMahJMgelN7o5x1DQNEBHJy4cNxgAVF8eDuGIBhoMTZqUPPxYfAT dhJgd1UbW7NookbBQ/tGkdWfIWxCgjolyYN8tkldqXH2qbStYm2NL4cPz6jS4Ttw z+iOnzqvcEge6l4uB22Fk3RuQDdt5zQTAYpvj/yWQQE+JaKnBGsRq4PvAgMBAAEw DQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQADgYEARaQVFkMedAk5RjFujP27i28rrGu7t3Tj3fh3EJzL wa/zFzfIes5deieIxPjP95OM7tFKyItU8d7eV4kkFkrMo3YYc3UPu0XXShf+aiEY 9iqwFZltjBpS0M7gEGcUkLerjrH0Ql7D3ZAXTkbYfOK6PF+yeFTa/B47/BNZf66c IJ4=
            -
        -
    -
-
samlp:status ..
    samlp:statuscode
        @Value:urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success
    -
-
saml:assertion ..
    @xmlns:xsi:http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance
    @xmlns:xs:http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
    @ID:_ea810b23d9de66fc807e994cbe3ac9109fa420f7a2
    @Version:2.0
    @IssueInstant:2017-05-23T10:51:29Z
    saml:issuerhttp://192.168.13.193:90/saml2/idp/metadata.php
    -
    ds:signature ..
        @xmlns:ds:http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#
        ds:signedinfo ..
            ds:canonicalizationmethod
                @Algorithm:http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#
            -
            ds:signaturemethod
                @Algorithm:http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1
            -
            ds:reference ..
                @URI:#_ea810b23d9de66fc807e994cbe3ac9109fa420f7a2
                ds:transforms ..
                    ds:transform
                        @Algorithm:http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature
                    -
                    ds:transform
                        @Algorithm:http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#
                    -
                -
                ds:digestmethod
                    @Algorithm:http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1
                -
                ds:digestvaluee32yH7wlMxxjWvbxLJIyofq5NkM=
                -
            -
        -
        ds:signaturevalueMIICdwIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCAmEwggJdAgEAAoGBAMahJMgelN7o5x1D QNEBHJy4cNxgAVF8eDuGIBhoMTZqUPPxYfATdhJgd1UbW7NookbBQ/tGkdWfIWxC gjolyYN8tkldqXH2qbStYm2NL4cPz6jS4Ttwz+iOnzqvcEge6l4uB22Fk3RuQDdt 5zQTAYpvj/yWQQE+JaKnBGsRq4PvAgMBAAECgYAZAdK6qzb89X+bbIsthSFQDdyP sjqYQr50aAeEayG/AxWcEMjOy/RyjdiYS3B5HvRHSi+/4/uaVIWFtr3kijtbbMAg bx99hJOntr41sbkUHDGuv3AFkytakiPyTRNU43EX8q8yWbn/TcmQ67yVtY8Qgmrx /5PwZudjjPYuCK6Z8QJBAORnz+zn5tryLYvDPEAFvM0Tn/l+RGFNL+8pfyQUMtS0 xq08ipiV1Ucq0Pj2jl7G3LmpTXqlybUM1/SEZL1dqScCQQDeoGjlQ1ar3GDc/lZh VmlTRzC+3bSoaWFsR/RqU+yfAWSgX4Ci05Rslksk4DhskJ61s2pORkxEIZ7IqVI5 ejv5AkEAmPWQwHW5G21N5Sg1RCbTfn8jBiFyR7s6W67tj0rbk6kQ2FkP9Al7kDJz ShdL1trUXJ2t3nICd/YG9aBoGo0LxwJBAJloH+AbjtXOflDKUeuxB9MC82wSijKi qydaTeoW+q5230hDhviso1JQHmfCuh7VaQf8IfzeJB+uqyPKyYYh3MECQEQiL+vE eegd4tA/zSthXcxBckLS3vwM0y4NlS401QFqiXhFzeVtn4KJYzAL4tD3G/ugBcWu 0t25UmbhOhNeJi0=
        -
        ds:keyinfo ..
            ds:x509data ..
                ds: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
                -
            -
        -
    -
    saml:subject ..
        saml:nameiddigupta
            @SPNameQualifier:google.com
            @Format:urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress
        -
        saml:subjectconfirmation ..
            @Method:urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer
            saml:subjectconfirmationdata
                @NotOnOrAfter:2017-05-23T10:56:29Z
                @Recipient:https://www.google.com/a/q3web.xyz/acs
                @InResponseTo:adkcgeadlnldphjjmkibfopehpmpomapchiamhip
            -
        -
    -
    saml:conditions ..
        @NotBefore:2017-05-23T10:50:59Z
        @NotOnOrAfter:2017-05-23T10:56:29Z
        saml:audiencerestriction ..
            saml:audiencegoogle.com
            -
        -
    -
    saml:authnstatement ..
        @AuthnInstant:2017-05-23T10:51:29Z
        @SessionNotOnOrAfter:2017-05-23T18:51:29Z
        @SessionIndex:_6a77305f32a09a41f85496e25ed10a418f5245a9d0
        saml:authncontext ..
            saml:authncontextclassrefurn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password
```

Relay State value is: 'https://www.google.com/a/q3web.xyz/ServiceLogin?service=analytics&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fanalytics.google.com&ss=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1&osid=1'

On trying to access google suite, I'm getting response:
**"G Suite - This account cannot be accessed because we could not parse the login request."**

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a computer person and I know nothing about coding, but after setting up my university-sponsored Gmail account, I was receiving this same "parse the login" error, regardless of the browser or device I was using. After reading a dozen forums that talked about problems with coding, Shibboleth incompatibility, device incompatibility, etc., I learned that simply clearing my browser caches and cookies fixed the issue.  I was told that it has something to do with my existing login credentials getting in the way of accessing Gmail as a new destination. I was also told that each time I change my master password at the university, I will similarly have to clear my caches and cookies in order to successfully login to my university-sponsored Gmail. This isn't a direct answer to your question, but maybe something here offers a clue to your mystery.  Good luck.